# Guessing game in TypeScript with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to figure out how to create a simple guessing game in TypeScript that will run in the terminal via Nodejs. I have the program somewhat working. It is not for any type of homework assignment or anything like that. I just wanted to try my hand at making a terminal application in TypeScript as I have done them in other languages. My code so far looks like:

```
const readline = require('readline');

// Number of attempts for user
let guessCount = 10;
// random number to compare
let randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
console.log(randomNumber);

console.log("Can you guess my number?");

// create the prompts
const readLineInterface = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});


readLineInterface.question("Between 1 - 100: ", function(status: string) {
    while(guessCount > 10) {    
        Number(status);
        if (Number(status)=== randomNumber) {
            console.log("You win!");
            process.exit(0);
        } else if (Number(status) < randomNumber) {
            guessCount -= 1;
            console.log("Too small! Try again.\n");
            readLineInterface.close();
        } else if (Number(status) > randomNumber) {
            guessCount -= 1;
            console.log("Too big! Try again.\n");
            readLineInterface.close();
        }
    }
});
```

I am able to get the program to compile and run but when I enter a guess it prints whether the guess was too low or too high but then stops registering input. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The win condition works just fine and immediately prints You win! then exits the program.

Comment: You are closing the interface... not sure what you expected; see [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#rlclose) about the `close` method.

Comment: I was hoping it would loop through based on the number of guesses left. Do I do the close after all of that but inside a loop?

Comment: I would put the close() before process.exit() and after the while loop

Comment: No that just made the program end immediately after printing Can you guess my number to the console. I am not sure why it isn't working properly.